# How Can I Solve Laravel / Guzzle Pool Error?

Tags: laravel, guzzle, pool

I would like to use http Pool at my laravel controller for taking api response. I' m taking error like "Internal Server Error" -statusCode: 500. But there is no record at laravel logs. What can be cause this error? Can you give me an idea? Thank you in advance..

```php
$responses = \Http::pool(function (Pool $pool) {
    return [
        $pool->as("example1")->post(
            config('app.api_url') . '/general/general_total_report',
            [
                'report_value' => '20',
                'report_table' => 'test',
                'positive' => 0
            ])
    ];
});

dd($responses);
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, it's also practically identical to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client). Do you have error_reporting enabled? If you do then the likely issue is server related

Comment: IF the response is `!=` than `OK()`, you can call the [logging facade](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/logging#log-levels) and  debug the `$responses`.

Comment: @francisco Hello, the api doesn't take any of posted data..

Comment: @RCeyda other HTTP methods work?

Comment: @francisco, I solved my problem via adding headers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$responses = Http::pool(function (Pool $pool) {
    $pool->as("flow")->baseUrl(config('app.api_url'))
        ->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'User-Agent' => "PHP-Request"])
        ->asForm()->post('/general/general_total_report', 
            [
            'report_value' => '20',
            'report_table' => 'test',
            'positive' => 0
            ]);
 });
```